# Get only filename from url in php without any variable values which exist in the url

Tags: php, url, get, filenames

I want to get filename without any `$_GET` variable values from a URL in php?

My URL is `http://learner.com/learningphp.php?lid=1348`

I only want to retrieve the  `learningphp.php` from the URL?

**How to do this?**

I used `basename()` function but it gives all the variable values also: `learntolearn.php?lid=1348` which are in the URL.

Comment: http://php.net/parse_url

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This should work:

```
echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

But beware of any malicious parts in your URL.

Comment: Okay, but the question mark is still output. This works fine for me: `echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);`.

Comment: Thanks, I was unsure whether the question mark was included or not in `QUERY_STRING`. Now the solution works.

Comment: But not for this URL: `http://www.example.com/path/script.php/test/?arg1=val1` ;)

Answer (score 42):

Following steps shows total information about how to get file, file with extension, file without extension. This technique is very helpful for me. Hope it will be helpful to you too.

```
  $url = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png';
        $file = file_get_contents($url); // to get file
        $name = basename($url); // to get file name
        $ext = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // to get extension
        $name2 =pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_FILENAME); //file name without extension
```

Comment: I don't understand why this has so many upvotes, it doesn't answer the question. If there is a query string on the end of the URL, it's included with the results here. OP wants the filename without the query string.

Comment: @jessica I know this is not the actual answer to the question so it's not a marked solution too. People are searching for various kinds of URLs when they are searching for URL like provided by me they are upvoting my ans.

Answer (score 35):

Is better to use `parse_url` to retrieve only the path, and then getting only the filename with the `basename`. This way we also avoid query parameters.

```
<?php

// url to inspect
$url = 'http://www.example.com/image.jpg?q=6574&t=987';

// parsed path
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

// extracted basename
echo basename($path);

?>
```

Is somewhat similar to [Sultan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41519521/155905) excepting that I'm using `component` `parse_url` parameter, to obtain only the path.

Comment: bingo, this is the only fully correct answer

Answer (score 24):

Your URL:

```
$url = 'http://learner.com/learningphp.php?lid=1348';
$file_name = basename(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
echo $file_name;
```

**output:** learningphp.php

Comment: Thank you for adding "output", it help to make it easier to understand what to expect.

Answer (score 22):

Use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) as Pekka said:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com/search.php?arg1=arg2';

$parts = parse_url($url);

$str = $parts['scheme'].'://'.$parts['host'].$parts['path'];

echo $str;
?>
```

http://codepad.org/NBBf4yTB

In this example the optional username and password aren't output!

Comment: sir, how do i get the whole url into the $url?

Comment: If you want to use the called URL: `$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Comment: but this won't give the 'http' in the $parts['scheme']

Comment: Parse the url `http://example.com/this/is/a/directory/path/file.php?bla=1`
You won't get the file name `file.php`, but the full path

Answer (score 10):

You can use,

```
$directoryURI =basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

echo $directoryURI;
```

Comment: This gives you an incorrect result if the running script name is not exactly the one called in the uri (e.g. using url_rewrite)

Answer (score 6):

An other way to get only the filename without querystring is by using parse_url and basename functions :

```
$parts = parse_url("http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/file.php?a=b&c=d");
$filename = basename($parts["path"]); // this will return 'file.php'
```

Comment: this turns into 98f3da9ae1c4dd972785fde37d21d3a9.jpg__ why the __ at the end ? edit: I used trim and fixed it

Answer (score 5):

Try the following code:

For PHP 5.4.0 and above:

```
$filename = basename(parse_url('http://learner.com/learningphp.php?lid=1348')['path']);
```

For PHP Version < 5.4.0

```
$parsed = parse_url('http://learner.com/learningphp.php?lid=1348');
$filename = basename($parsed['path']);
```

Comment: Answer is the same as CROZET's one.

Answer (score 4):

```
$filename = pathinfo( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_PATH ), PATHINFO_FILENAME );
```

Use parse_url to extract the path from the URL, then pathinfo returns the filename from the path

Comment: please format your answer appropriately (use backticks for inline code and 4-space indentation for blocks of code)

Answer (score 2):

The answer there assumes you know that the URL is coming from a request, which it may very well not be.  The generalized answer would be something like:

```
$basenameWithoutParameters = explode('?', pathinfo($yourURL, PATHINFO_BASENAME))[0];
```

Here it just takes the base path, and splits out and ignores anything ? and after.

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "learner.com/learningphp.php?lid=1348";
$l = parse_url($url);
print_r(stristr($l['path'], "/"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
function getScriptName()
{
    $filename = baseName($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $ipos = strpos($filename, "?");
    if ( !($ipos === false) )   $filename = substr($filename, 0, $ipos);
    return $filename;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be i am late

```
$e = explode("?",basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
$filename = $e[0];
```