# Upload a file to web server Delphi + php

Tags: php, delphi, delphi-xe, indy

i am working on a program and i need to upload a 'log.txt' to a webserver.. by http

i've searched and got to this :-

Delphi XE :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
idhttp1.Post('http://127.0.0.1/GET2.php', 'C:\Users\Someone\Desktop\log.txt')
end;
```

---

php :-

```
<?php
$uploaddir = "uploads/";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
{
  echo "The file has been uploaded successfully";
}
else
{
  echo "There was an error uploading the file";
}
?>
```

---

but no files being uploaded

thanks for your help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Read the PHP documentation.

Your PHP code is using [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php), which expects the client to post an HTML webform in MIME `multipart/form-data` format:

[Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) > [POST method uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

> PHP is capable of receiving file uploads from any **RFC-1867** compliant browser.

[RFC 1867 Form-based File Upload in HTML](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867.html)

But that format is not what your application is actually posting, though.  It is simply posting the raw file content as-is with no MIME metadata to describe the file.  That is why your PHP code is not working.

To post a `multipart/form-data` HTML webform using `TIdHTTP.Post()`, you have to use the `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` class, eg:

```
uses
  ..., IdHTTP, IdMultipartFormDataStream;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  PostData: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
begin
  PostData := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
  try
    PostData.AddFile('file', 'C:\Users\Someone\Desktop\log.txt');
    idhttp1.Post('http://127.0.0.1/GET2.php', PostData)
  finally
    PostData.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively, PHP also supports HTTP `PUT` requests for file uploads:

[Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) > [PUT method support](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php)

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FS: TFileStream;
begin
  FS := TFileStream.Create('C:\Users\Someone\Desktop\log.txt', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    idhttp1.Put('http://127.0.0.1/log.txt', FS);
  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

```
<?php
/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

/* Open a file for writing */
$fp = fopen("log.txt", "w");

/* Read the data 1 KB at a time
   and write to the file */
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
  fwrite($fp, $data);

/* Close the streams */
fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
?>
```

Comment: thats answers my Question ,  Solved.

Comment: @David Heffernan  : i didn't have the privileges to accept answers back then !! sir are you having a bad day ?  you down voted everything i ever posted in stackoverflow and gave me  political style execuses.

Comment: You can always accept answers. Thanks for doing this one.

Comment: hi i tried these code and it's working. but the output always be log.txt is there a way to make the output file following the original source name?

Comment: @Miranachan When using `POST` with `$_FILES`, the source filename is in `$_FILES['fieldName']['name']`, per [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) I had linked to in my answer.  When using `PUT` with `fopen("php://input")`, the source filename is in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, you will have to parse out the filename, see [Get only filename from url in php without any variable values which exist in the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852296/).

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for the reply. okay i'll take a look of those refrences