# How to get file name and clean url

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, regex

I have these urls and I need to remove the first part to get the file name:

```
http://isonex.ru/upload/iblock/ebd/ebdbd2a3961fc73170978ae4995b5a4b.jpeg    
http://isonex.ru/upload/iblock/62a/62a5e49b20e498bfef00d81fa03403c8.jpeg
```

How can I clean the url to get only the file names?
For example:

```
ebdbd2a3961fc73170978ae4995b5a4b.jpeg
62a5e49b20e498bfef00d81fa03403c8.jpeg
c0004e9ab6e749b4bfc70d652722e966.jpeg
```

Comment: Quick and dirty: `var filename = url.split("/").pop();`

Comment: You have it in browser url bar or you want to copy them to script?

Comment: IM USING PHP SCRIPT. how to loop every line from a file?

Comment: it seems as possible duplcate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852296/get-only-filename-from-url-in-php-without-any-variable-values-which-exist-in-the

Answer (score 0):

Since, you tagged `PHP`, you can use [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function.

```
<?php


echo basename("http://isonex.ru/upload/iblock/ebd/ebdbd2a3961fc73170978ae4995b5a4b.jpeg"),"\n";
echo basename("http://isonex.ru/upload/iblock/62a/62a5e49b20e498bfef00d81fa03403c8.jpeg");
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ebdbd2a3961fc73170978ae4995b5a4b.jpeg
62a5e49b20e498bfef00d81fa03403c8.jpeg
```