# How to get part of url before last slash with PHP?

Tags: php, url

I have URL like

`https://example.com/something/this-is-my-part/10448887`

and want to have

`this-is-my-part`

only.

Is there an option for this?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133436/get-a-sub-directory-folder-in-the-url-and-echo-it) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) might help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get only filename from url in php without any variable values which exist in the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852296/get-only-filename-from-url-in-php-without-any-variable-values-which-exist-in-the)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$parts = explode('/', $path);
$part = $parts[count($parts) - 2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
$url = "https://example.com/something/this-is-my-part/10448887";
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode("/", $path);
echo $segments[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Remove final slash if it exists
$string = rtrim($string, '/');
// Explode the string into an array
$parts = explode('/', $string);
// Echo 2nd to last item
echo $parts[count($parts) - 2];
```